# Gauss - Green theorem for Sobolev $H^1$ space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I know the Gauss-Green theorem:

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, bounded set with $∂U$ being $C^1$. Suppose $u ∈ C^1(\bar U)$, then 
$$∫_U u_{x_i} dx = \int_{∂U} u \nu^i dS,$$

where $\nu=(\nu^1,…\nu^n)$ denotes the outward-pointing unit normal vector field to the region $U$.

**My question is:** 
How to prove that this theorem is true with the weaker assumption that $u \in H^1(U)$?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

$$\mathcal C^1(\bar U)\text{ is dense in }H^1(U).$$

**Edit**

$\mathcal C^1(\bar U)$ dense in $H^1(U)$ mean that if $u\in H^1(U)$, there exist a sequence $(u_n)\subset \mathcal C^1(\bar U)$ s.t. $$\|u_n-u\|_{H^1(U)}\underset{n\to \infty  }{\longrightarrow  } 0.$$
Therefore $$\int_{U}|u_n-u|^2+\sum_{i=1}^n\int_U|\partial _i u_n-\partial _i u|^2=0.$$

In paticular, since $U$ is bounded, $$\left|\int_{U}\partial _i u_n-\int_U \partial _iu\right|^2\leq C\int _U |\partial _iu_n-\partial _iu|^2,$$ by Jensen's inequality. Then you can get one limit. For $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\partial U}u_n\nu _i=\int_{\partial U}u\nu ^i,$$ it's a consequence of the continuity of the trace operator.

Comment: Ok, so I've got that there exists a sequence $(u^{(m)}) \in C^1(\bar U)$ such that $u^{(m)} \to u$ in $H^1(U)$. Since  $(u^{(m)}) \in C^1(\bar U)$, I've got 

$$\int_U u_{x_i}^{(m)} dx = \int_{\partial U} u^{(m)} \nu^i dS.$$

Now I need to go to the limit under the integral sign but I have no idea what to use.

Comment: @WawMath: I edited my answer.